# What is the advantage of using 'tar' today?

Tags: linux, unix, archiving, tar

I know that `tar` was made for tape archives back in the day, but today we have archive file formats that both aggregate files and perform compression within the same logical file format.

Questions:

- Is there a performance penalty during the aggregation/compression/decompression stages for using `tar` encapsulated in `gzip` or `bzip2`, when compared to using a file format that does aggregation and compression in the same data structure? Assume the runtime of the compressor being compared is identical (e.g. gzip and Deflate are similar).
- Are there features of the `tar` file format that other file formats, such as `.7z` and `.zip` do not have?
- Since `tar` is such an old file format, and newer file formats exist today, why is `tar` (whether encapsulated in `gzip`, `bzip2` or even the new `xz`) still so widely used today on GNU/Linux, Android, BSD, and other such UNIX operating systems, for file transfers, program source and binary downloads, and sometimes even as a package manager format?

Comment: It's a very good question. I too highly dislike their whole operation of installing software with either odd names or that I can't simply apt-get. Only reason why I can see it getting downvoted is that this is more of a question for Unix/Linux. However SU should accept this.

Comment: @Griffin: The question is not about installing software from tarballs. It is about using the Tar format (e.g. over Zip or RAR)

Comment: I disagree that it "wastes time". If you mean performance, there is no actual performance penalty for tar as the format is very efficient. If you mean it wastes *your* time, I don't see how `tar xvzf` is harder than `7z -x`...

Comment: Allquixotic, I mean that you have to extract the archive twice, the first time to extract the tar, adn the second to extract from the tar.

Comment: He seems to be lamenting the fact that tar does not store a catalog at the start, so gui compression tools that want to list the contents prior to extracting have to decompress the whole tar just to list the contents, then they decompress it again when extracting.

Comment: @MarcusJ Usually, the tar.xx formats have a one-line solution.  If you have tar.gz, for example, you could use `tar -xzf <file>.tar.gz` and it will decompress and extract all at once.

Comment: psusi, no no no, I'm talking about the fact that tar needs a separate compressor and decompressor, so basically when you open a  tar.gz, you need to extract BOTH the gz file to get the tar, then have to extract the tar file, instead of merely decompressing something like a 7z - in one step. It takes more cpu power to do it like this, and seems redundant.

Comment: @MarcusJ, both steps have to be done either way, so it takes no more cpu power.

Comment: Not to say you're wrong or anything, but how would a 7z require both steps? It would merely load the file, then decompress whatever was selected to be decompressed. :/

Comment: @MarcusJ: you think 7z somehow magically knows where each file starts in an archive? Besides, the usual compression algorithms (gzip, bzip2) work with streaming the content: no need to complete 100% the first stage before next.

Comment: Which step do you think it doesn't have to do?  It has to parse the file format, and it has to decompress the content.  The difference is really just in the order the two are done.  `tar` decompresses the content first, then parses the archive.  `7zip` parses the archive, then decompresses the file content ( the metadata is uncompressed ).

Comment: Also @MarcusJ you seem to be confusing two different things: when you do `tar xvzf`, the uncompressed data **is not** written to hard disk in `.tar` format! You're right that if you ran `gunzip blah.tar.gz` and then `tar xf blah.tar`, it would write the data to disk twice (once as a .tar and again as files in the filesystem), but nobody actually does it that way. The `tar xzf` uses a **UNIX Pipe** (basically a memory copy) to transfer the uncompressed data from `gzip` (or whatever compressor) to `tar`, so the data is **not** written to disk in `.tar` format.

Comment: @grawity I understand that. I was simply trying ensure him that it wouldn't be downvoted. Judging by the responce I don't think he's in too much fear of that anymore.

Comment: One thing I know is that `tar` (especially compressed) behaves awfully when it comes to data corruption. Small redundancy / recovery data added by modern formats is worth gold

Comment: `tar` is superior for streaming. Unlike `zip`, you don't have to wait for the central directory.  For archiving, this can also be a disadvantage (slower to list contents). `tar xvzf` will also automatically use two processes/cores, so it's not inefficient to split the two processes.

Comment: @PPC: that's what PAR files are for. Tar is an unix utility; as such, error correction is best left to dedicated tools.

Comment: Hmm, tar keeps soft links. I can recall back in the doing: "tar cf - | ( cd /somewhere/else ; tar xf -)" rather a lot because "cp" didn't have a flag to respect soft links. Don't know if it does today - if I encountered the problem, I'd probably just use 'tar' this way again.

Comment: Why use 1 command when 2 suffice?

Comment: @Kruug: GNU tar automatically applies the `z` (or `j`, or `J`) flag: `tar xf foo.tar.gz`. It does this based on the actual content of the file, not its name, so it still works even if a gzipped tar file is named `foo.tar`.

Comment: @psusi however, if you want to extract just a single file, AFAIK tar have to decompress the whole archive first, while another format could only decompress the target file instead.

Answer (score 181):

### Part 1: Performance

Here is a comparison of two separate workflows and what they do.

You have a file on disk `blah.tar.gz` which is, say, 1 GB of gzip-compressed data which, when uncompressed, occupies 2 GB (so a compression ratio of 50%).

The way that you would create this, if you were to do archiving and compression separately, would be:

```
tar cf blah.tar files ...
```

This would result in `blah.tar` which is a mere aggregation of the `files ...` in uncompressed form.

Then you would do

```
gzip blah.tar
```

This would read the contents of `blah.tar` from disk, compress them through the gzip compression algorithm, write the contents to `blah.tar.gz`, then unlink (delete) the file `blah.tar`.

Now, let's decompress!

#### Way 1

You have `blah.tar.gz`, one way or another.

You decide to run:

```
gunzip blah.tar.gz
```

This will

- READ the 1 GB compressed data contents of `blah.tar.gz`.
- PROCESS the compressed data through the `gzip` decompressor in memory.
- As the memory buffer fills up with "a block" worth of data, WRITE the uncompressed data into the file `blah.tar` on disk and repeat until all the compressed data is read.
- Unlink (delete) the file `blah.tar.gz`.

Now, you have `blah.tar` on disk, which is uncompressed but contains one or more files within it, with very low data structure overhead. The file size is probably *a couple of bytes* larger than the sum of all the file data would be.

You run:

```
tar xvf blah.tar
```

This will

- READ the 2 GB of uncompressed data contents of `blah.tar` and the `tar` file format's data structures, including information about file permissions, file names, directories, etc.
- WRITE the 2 GB of data plus the metadata to disk. This involves: translating the data structure / metadata information into creating new files and directories on disk as appropriate, or rewriting existing files and directories with new data contents.

The total data we **READ** from disk in this process was 1 GB (for gunzip) + 2 GB (for tar) = 3 GB.

The total data we **WROTE** to disk in this process was 2 GB (for gunzip) + 2 GB (for tar) + a few bytes for metadata = about 4 GB.

#### Way 2

You have `blah.tar.gz`, one way or another.

You decide to run:

```
tar xvzf blah.tar.gz
```

This will

- READ the 1 GB compressed data contents of `blah.tar.gz`, a block at a time, into memory.
- PROCESS the compressed data through the `gzip` decompressor in memory.
- As the memory buffer fills up, it will **pipe** that data, in memory, through to the `tar` file format parser, which will read the information about metadata, etc. and the uncompressed file data.
- As the memory buffer fills up in the `tar` file parser, it will WRITE the uncompressed data to disk, by creating files and directories and filling them up with the uncompressed contents.

The total data we **READ** from disk in this process was 1 GB of compressed data, period.

The total data we **WROTE** to disk in this process was 2 GB of uncompressed data + a few bytes for metadata = about 2 GB.

If you notice, the amount of disk I/O in **Way 2** is *identical* to the disk I/O performed by, say, the `Zip` or [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) programs, adjusting for any differences in compression ratio.

And if compression ratio is your concern, use the `Xz` compressor to encapsulate `tar`, and you have [LZMA2'ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm#LZMA2_format) TAR archive, which is just as efficient as the most advanced algorithm available to 7-Zip :-)

### Part 2: Features

`tar` stores Unix permissions within its file metadata, and is very well known and tested for successfully packing up a directory with all kinds of different permissions, symbolic links, etc. There are more than a few instances where one might need to glob a bunch of files into a single file or stream, but not necessarily compress it (although compression is useful and often used).

### Part 3: Compatibility

Many tools are distributed in source or binary form as .tar.gz or .tar.bz2, because it is a "lowest common denominator" file format: much like most Windows users have access to .zip or .rar decompressors, most Linux installations, even the most basic, will have access to at least tar and gunzip, no matter how old or pared down. Even Android firmwares have access to these tools.

New projects targeting audiences running modern distributions may very well distribute in a more modern format, such as .tar.xz (using the Xz (LZMA) compression format, which compresses better than gzip or bzip2), or .7z, which is similar to the ZIP or [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) file formats in that it both compresses and specifies a layout for encapsulating multiple files into a single file.

You don't see .7z used more often for the same reason that music isn't sold from online download stores in brand new formats like [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28audio_format%29), or video in [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM). Compatibility with people running ancient or very basic systems.

Comment: Kudos for great answer with all the content separated under three distinct headers.

Comment: "Part 3: Compatibility" appears to have been copied from @Kruug's answer.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy Have you noticed that it was allquixotic who originally wrote that part and edited it into Kruug's answer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice.  However it seems a bit silly to me to have an identical block of text in two different answers on this page.

Comment: I don't have enough repo to add an answer so I write here: AFAIK tar's fault tolerance is much higher than other similar tools. If you have to save something from a not so reliable medium (for example network fs.) tar is probably the best tool for saving as much data as it is possible. Rsync and other tools failed when the first error happened, but with tar we were able to pass single errors. (It was a not so critical daily backup.)

Comment: ^ i think "higher fault tolerance" there actually means 'does not notice errors and will blindly stumble on, whether you want it to or not'!

Comment: This answers why `tar` fits in the archiving ecosystem (ie, to aggregate files together, providing a performance boost and some other benefits like permissions saving), but it does not address why modern alternatives such as `dar` aren't used in place. In other words, this answer justifies the usage of files aggregators, but not of the `tar` software in itself.

Answer (score 103):

This [has been answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295860/why-do-people-use-tarballs).

> bzip and gzip work on single files, not groups of files. Plain old zip (and pkzip) operate on groups of files and have the concept of the archive built-in.
>
> The *nix philosophy is one of small tools that do specific jobs very well and can be chained together. That's why there's two tools here that have specific tasks, and they're designed to fit well together. It also means you can use tar to group files and then you have a choice of compression tool (bzip, gzip, etc).

Many tools are distributed in source or binary form as .tar.gz or .tar.bz2, because it is a "lowest common denominator" file format: much like most Windows users have access to .zip or .rar decompressors, most Linux installations, even the most basic, will have access to at least `tar` and `gunzip`, no matter how old or pared down. Even Android firmwares have access to these tools.

New projects targeting audiences running modern distributions may very well distribute in a more modern format, such as `.tar.xz` (using the Xz ([LZMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm)) compression format, which compresses better than gzip or bzip2), or .7z, which is similar to the [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) or [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) file formats in that it both compresses and specifies a layout for encapsulating multiple files into a single file.

You don't see .7z used more often for the same reason that music isn't sold from online download stores in brand new formats like [Opus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28audio_codec%29), or video in [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM). Compatibility with people running ancient or very basic systems is important.

Comment: Hi @Kruug, I edited your post just to give a practical perspective on why people still *choose* to use these formats when they have a choice to use something else. I didn't change the text you already had. This is just to ensure that what appears to be the canonical answer to this question will have the full picture. Feel free to edit my edit if you want :)

Comment: @allquixotic inception anyone? Edit the edit of and edit so you can edit an edit...

Comment: @allquixotic I feel a bit bad, getting all of these upvotes when at least 50% of the answer was yours.

Comment: This answer is definitely a case of "I'm sometimes blown away by undeserved upvotes". It does not address the core issue of the question which is with listing the contents of compressed tar and it's not even an original answer!

Comment: @Kruug Don't feel bad now; I posted my own answer ;-D

Comment: WebM might not be the best example since it is technically inferior to the more popular H.264 codec.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин: This answer provides the rationale for using `tar` from a Unix/Linux user's perspective, which readers are finding helpful. It deserves my upvote.

Comment: Actually, most stock Android firmwares have an unzip and use renamed and optimized zip files as their application delivery format, and they may have a gzip, but they do not have a tar.  Alternate installations often have a more complete unix toolset.

Comment: -1 for great justice.  this should have been a comment.

Comment: I don't buy the legacy/lowest common denominator argument; I remember on new systems (sun) frequently having to download gzip/gunzip (from sunfreeware) just to install other tar.gz packaged software (plus gnu tar, since sun's tar sucked). For legacy/lower-common denominator, you had `tar.Z` (compress/uncompress). The progression of utilities has been a constant stream (no pun intended) of change & improvement: Z => zip => gz => bz2 => 7z => xz  (or whatever order you prefer). As for tar's role, some utils un/compress only, and still require tar to bundle up file hierarchies.

Comment: @michael_n, the progression of *compression* tools has continued, yet we still use tar as the container format.  The question made it clear it was talking about that, not the compression.

Comment: I highly disagree that xz achieves better compression than a .7z archive. The 7-zip file format supports a wide variety of compression algorithms including LZMA(2) which is its "home" compression algorithm and was developed by the the 7-zip developer.

From the xz wiki article: "xz is essentially a stripped down version of the 7-Zip program, which uses its own file format rather than the .7z format used by 7-Zip which lacks support for Unix-like file system metadata."

Comment: XZ uses LZMA2 as its compression algorithm. The only difference is that 7-zip has a different metadata format. The mathematics used to compress the files is exactly the same as LZMA2. Certain input data can yield better compression ratios if you use PPMD compression in 7-zip, but the runtime and memory costs of PPMD far exceed any other compression algorithm in existence, both for compression and decompression.

Comment: LZMA on the other hand decompresses very fast (almost as fast as zip, and much much faster than it compresses). PPMD, while it may save a few kilobytes on several dozen megabytes of data, will take gigabytes of memory to decompress, and will decompress just as slowly as it compresses (slooooooooooooooooooooooooooow). So, throwing out ppmd as being impractical, Xz and 7-Zip are identical in compression capability, varying insignificantly based on the way they store file structure and metadata.

Comment: @psusi yeah, I know / understand / agree / etc. And now (gnu) tar compresses, too, in a variety of formats (gz/bz/xz/yada-yada-yada-z): time rolls on, lines blur, things change, and sun's tar still doesn't handle long file/path names. (...arguably for "posix compliance", but no need to delve into pedantry (my fault) and lose the larger point (whatever it was, i forget))

Answer (score 64):

Tar has a rich set of operations and modifiers that know all about Unix files systems. It knows about Unix permissions, about the different times associated with files, about hard links, about softlinks (and about the possibility that symbolic links could introduce cycles in the filesystem graph), and allow you to specify several different ways for managing all this data.

- Do you want the extracted data to preserve file access times? **Tar can do that.** To preserve permissions? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to preserve symbolic links as symbolic links? **Tar does that by default.** Want to copy the target instead? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to be sure hardlinked data is only stored once (that is, to do the right thing)? **Tar does that.**
- Do you want to handle sparse files well? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want uncompressed data (why?)? **Tar can do that.** To compress with gzip? **Tar can do that.** With bzip2? **Tar can do that.** With arbitrary external compression programs? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to write or recover to/from a raw device? **Tar's format handles that fine.**
- Do you want to add files to an existing archive? **Tar can do that.** To diff two archive to see what changed? **Tar can do that.** To update only those parts of the archive that have changed? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to be sure you don't archive across more than one filesystem? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to grab only files that are newer than your last backup? **Tar can do that.**
- Do you want to preserve user and group names or numbers? **Tar can do either one.**
- Do you need to preserve device nodes (like the files in `/dev`) so that after extraction, the system will run correctly? **Tar can do that.**

Tar has been evolving to handle lots and lots of use cases for decades and really does know *a lot* about the things people want to do with Unix filesystems.

Comment: You don't need GNU tar to use an arbitrary compressor: just tell tar to write the archive to stdout with `f -` and pipe it to the compressor.

Comment: "Do you want uncompressed data (why?)?" I use `tar` very often to copy a filesystem tree from one place to another and preserve permissions, etc., and compression in this case just takes extra CPU cycles. E.g. `tar cf - * | tar xf - -C /somewhere`.

Comment: Additionally, you would want a .tar file when the destination filesystem performs de-duplication.   Creating compressed archives on a filesystem that performs de-duplication will substantially lower the dedupe ratio.  Example:  We once deleted a $10,000.00 tar.gz file; meaning, it was taking up $10k worth of storage space because someone used compression.

Comment: @Steve CPU cycles may be cheaper than disk IO for algorithms like LZ4 or LZO. That's why they're used in zram, and transparent compression file systems like NTFS, ZFS, Btrfs... so sometimes it's actually faster than to compress since the amount of disk IO is greatly reduced

Answer (score 31):

You confuse the two distinct processes of *archiving* and *compression*.

**Reasons for using an archiver**

One reason to use archiving without compression is, for instance, if a bunch
of files is copied from one host to another. A command like the following

```
tar cf - some_directory | ssh host "(cd ~/somewhere | tar xf -)"
```

can speed up things considerably. If I know that the files cannot be
compressed or if [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is set up with compression, it can save considerable CPU
time. Sure, one can use a more modern compressing tool with an archiving function
and turn off the compression. The advantage of `tar` is, that I can expect it
to be available on every system.

**Reasons for using an archiver with gzip compression**

One reason that I use `tar` with `gzip` is: *speed!*
If I want to transfer a few GiB of text files from one place to another, I
don't care about squeezing out the last bytes, since the compression is only
used for transit, not for long-term storage. In those cases I use `gzip`,
which doesn't max out the CPU (in contrast to [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip), for instance), which
means that I'm [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) bound again and not CPU bound. And again: `gzip` can be
considered available everywhere.

**Reasons for using `tar` in favour of `scp`, `rsync`, etc.**

It beats `scp` if you have a lot of small files to copy (for example, a mail directories with hundred thousands of files). `rsync`, awesome as it is, might not be available everywhere. Further, `rsync` only really pays off if part of the files - or an older version- - is already present on the destination. For the initial copy `tar` is the fastest, with compression or without, depending on the actual data.

Comment: But if you're going to archive, why not compress as well? Okay, yeah it can save time for files that aren't easily compressed, but then archivers should probably know that music for example, aren't very compressible, except for the headers.

Comment: You may not need to, or your content might not be compressible.

Comment: For performance reasons it is often easier to use uncompressed file aggregation when sending data over very high bandwidth network links that exceed the speed at which the compressor can compress data. This is achievable for example with Gigabit Ethernet; only a few well-designed compression algorithms, which also have very poor compression ratio, can compress data that fast even on a large desktop CPU. On an embedded device you have even less CPU time to work with.

Comment: @MarcusJ there are also all sorts of "uncompressible" binary file formats, running them through a compressor is a waste of time/CPU. `tar` however will archive them, making their transfer easier and faster. As you said, compressors can know about some of them (mp3 for example) and guess some others from the magic number , but not all.

Comment: not only is this speeding up things but it also allows preserving file ownership, timestamps and attributes (if the user privileges allow it)

Comment: It seems easier to use the pipe `| ssh host tar x -C '~/somewhere'`

Comment: @DietrichEpp That doesn't work on Solaris.

Comment: @AndreHolzner Right.  I often do `tar cf - . | (cd ~/somewhere; tar xvf -)`.  It is really useful not to have to wait until the central index is written (like for example in a zip file).

Comment: Why would you use this rather than `scp`, `rsync`, SFTP or any of the other file transfer protocols though?

Comment: @Konrad: you can perform that kind of transfer using tar using very simple network tools like netcat. scp, rsync sftp or such implies running much more complex client and server software.

Answer (score 25):

Adding to the other good answers here, I prefer the combination `tar` + `gzip|bzip2|xz` mainly because these compressed files are like streams, and you can pipe them easily.

I need to uncompress a file available in the internet. With either `zip` or `rar` formats I have to download it first and then uncompress it. With `tar.{gz,bz2,xz}` I can download and uncompress in the same step, without need to having the compressed archive phisically on disk:

```
curl -s http://example.com/some_compressed_file.tar.gz | tar zx
```

This will leave just the uncompressed files in my disk, and will speed up the whole process, because I am not waisting time first downloading the entire file and after the download finishes I uncompress it. Instead, I am uncompressing it while it is downloading. You cannot do this with `zip` or `rar` files.

Comment: I don't know about rar ( it's a terrible program that only seems to have become popular with pirates beacuse of its ability to split into multiple smaller files ), but you can stream zip just fine.  The man page even mentions it.  It also has the advantage of being able to extract or update files from the middle of a large archive efficiently, though tar tends to get slightly better compression.  Compression vs. random access is a tradeoff.

Comment: @psusi incorrect. You can do hacks like [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/26474/unzipping-files-that-are-flying-in-through-a-pipe), but what it does is download all the file in memory and then unzip it, instead of unzipping while downloading. And `funzip` just extracts the first file in the zipfile, not all.

Comment: Ahh, while you can pipe the output of `zip`, it appears that `unzip` is buggy and can't read from stdin.  This is a defect in the program though, not a limitation of the file format.

Comment: No offense, but when on Earth is this an issue nowadays?

Comment: @Stu just to clarify, is not an issue, is just optimizing your time (I don't care about space if that's what you thought)

Comment: I use `tar` on the other end (the sending side, rather than the receiving side), since gnu tar has really flexible options for including/excluding files, over, say `scp -r`, e.g,. `tar -czh  --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git --exclude=*~ --exclude=*.bak -f - some_dir | ssh user@rmt_host "cat > ~/some_dir.tgz"` (avoids creating local tar.gz before sending, too)

Comment: Both sides work: You can tar on one side and untar in the other, too: `tar zc /some/folder | ssh user@host "cd /other/folder && tar zx"`

Comment: @psusi as I remember from old times when using pkzip to store files on multiple floppies, zip store catalog at end of archive. It always request last floppy for start extraction or show catalog. So http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ZIP-64_Internal_Layout.svg

Comment: @mmv-ru, oh yea, it is backwards, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 14):

There are several reasons to stick with (GNU) Tar.

It is:

- GPL licensed
- good in the sense of Unix philosophy

  - single purpose tool, capable of doing several tasks
- well documented and has many trusted features
- compatible with several compression algorithms
- easy to use and people have have developed habits with it
- broadly available
- **I feel warm and fuzzy inside when using software started by [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman)** (excluding [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs))

If your particular beef is with having to "decompress" a tarball before being able to read the contents, then you're probably right. [WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) and [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) do it automatically. However, there are simple workarounds to this problem such as documenting the content of an archive in an uncompressed form.

Comment: It's free software - So are a lot of them
It's good at what it does - Hardly compared to other stuff
It's well documented and has many features - Features are hardly used and detestably easy to use.
It supports several compression algorithms - Not as many as some others

Comment: the Unix Gods created it - therefore we must use it!

Comment: Tar also stores UNIX permissions natively, and is very well known and tested.  There's more than a few instances where one might need to glob a bunch of files into a single file or stream, but not necessarily compress it.

Comment: Luckily tar is not limited to just GNU versions.  While GNU tar is certainly a good piece of software, libarchive + related front ends are much faster and easy to embed in other software projects. You can make an argument for tar without turning it into a licensing fight.

Comment: @Lucas Holt Very true, I mention it in parentheses only because it's the only version I'm familiar with.

Comment: having used other tar's, gnu tar is the only one I would trust to work consistently & correctly. Especially on solaris, but also a bit cautious with native (proprietary) tar's on hp-ux/aix & z/os.

Comment: Downvote. Sarcasm is inappropriate on Stackexchange. People do actually trust these answers.

Comment: I'm not sarcastic. I like RMS and the way he carries forth his believes.

Comment: Sarcasm and sincerity travels poorly across plain text.  We usually guess about it from your tone of voice.  Guessing someone is serious or not on the internet is a bit difficult.

Comment: @Warren P thanks for the comment. I'll try to maintain a neutral tone in the future.

Answer (score 12):

## Performance

The big difference is the order that the compression and archiving are done in. `tar` archives, then can optionally send the archive to a compressor, and `zip` builds up the archive, and compresses the file data in 32 KB chunks as it is inserted into the archive. By breaking the file data up into small chunks and compressing them separately, it allows you to extract specific files or parts of files without having to decompress everything in the archive before it. It also prevents the compressor from building up a very large dictionary before it is restarted. This means compression will go faster, but not give as good of a ratio as compressing the whole thing with a larger dictionary size.

You can visualize it by thinking of two files, where the first 500 bytes of the second file are the same as the last 500 bytes of the first file. With the `zip` method, the compressor is restarted for the second file, so does not remember that the first file ended in the same data, so it can't remove the duplicate data from the second file.

## Popularity

There are plenty of other formats that have a number of advantages over `tar`. [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) doesn't store Unix file permissions, but `dar` does, and `zip` can, and all three store an index, which allows for fast browsing, extraction of a subset of files, and updating files within the archive. They can also use multi-core CPUs for compression.

The reason everyone still uses `tar` is the same reason everyone still uses Windows, and [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash): people don't like change. Without a strong reason to change, people just stick to what they know. `dar` doesn't provide enough of a benefit to justify publishing files in the format when most people already have `tar` installed, and very few know about `dar`, so simple inertia keeps us on the old standard.

Comment: zip can store and restore the Unix permissions.  The zip and unzip utilities from InfoZIP normally distributed with Unix system does this.

Comment: zip does not compress the file in 32K chunks.  You are confusing the sliding window size of 32K with how the compression is done.

Comment: gzip -9 does not have a 900 kB dictionary.  All levels of gzip use a 32K dictionary.  You may be thinking of bzip2.

Comment: So much misinformation in one answer.

Comment: @MarkAdler, it appears zip has been extended to store the file mode, but not owner.  7zip still warns it does not handle unix permissions.  Zip ( and cab ) does compress 32k blocks at a time, else it could not efficiently extract a file from the middle of a large archive, which is the problem tar has.  7z, rar, and dar have an option to use the blocking method ( like zip ) or "solid" mode ( like tar ), as they call it.  Re: -9, it seems I was thinking of bzip2 and lzma, and gzip uses a more simplistic system, but it does not use a fixed 32k dictionary, but the window limits it near there.

Comment: The zip format can store both the uid and gid.

Comment: You need to either make corrections to your answer or delete your answer.

Comment: @MarkAdler, I once worked on the cab extractor for ReactOS, trust me, it it compresses 32k at a time, either combining smaller files or splitting larger ones as needed.

Comment: When working on the CAB format, it might have been a good idea to spend some time studying the cab format specification.  The 32K CFDATA blocks are _not_ random access entry points.  The random access points are at the start of CAB "folders", which consist of a series of CFDATA blocks.  From the specification: "By default, all files are added to a single folder (compression history) in the cabinet."  So a non-default option would be needed for CAB file to have any random access midpoints at all.

Comment: Your edited answer has improved, but is still chock full of misinformation.  zip does not compress in 32K chunks, and does not provide access to parts of files without having to decompress the entire file.  "It also prevents the compressor from building up a very large dictionary before it is restarted." is nonsensical.  There is no building up of anything.  The deflate dictionary is simply the 32K bytes that precede the next byte to be compressed.  Once you get past the first 32K, the dictionary is always the same size, there is no "building up", and the compression speed does not change.

Comment: Because the data stream is broken into a series of CFDATA blocks that are limited in size, that does in fact, provide for random access, since you can seek to any CFDATA block and start decompression there.  The folder mechanism is a seemingly useless abstraction.  As I said, the deflate dictionary is not *strictly* limited to 32k, though in practice it tends to not grow much larger due to the 32k distance limit, but inf-zip allows for bzip2, which has no such limit.  Whatever the limits of the compression algorithm, restarting it does reduce compression ratios.

Comment: No, you cannot start decompressing at any CFDATA block.  Read the specification, which is very clear on this point.  Within a folder, each CFDATA block can and does use the previous CFDATA blocks as history for compression.  The folder is the only abstraction in the specification that defines where you can start decompressing, so it is not only useful, but essential for the random extraction application you are calling attention to in your answer.

Comment: The deflate dictionary _is_ strictly limited to 32K.  It does not "grow" once you're at least 32K into the stream. From there on it is always _exactly_ 32K.  bzip2 certainly does have a limit of 900K of history, which is not a sliding dictionary but rather a block on which the BWT transform is applied.  Each block is compressed independently, and cannot make use of the information in previous blocks.

Comment: Since there seems to be no limit to the amount of misinformation you can fabricate, this is no longer productive.  I am done commenting on this answer and related comments.  Thank you and good night.

Comment: I disagree that dar doesn't provide enough of a benefit to justify the change: it is way more robust and way less susceptible to corruption (ie, tar is a solid archive whereas dar is not and thus allows partial file extraction, even if corrupted, whereas you lose all your files in a corrupted tar). In addition, most modern archiving features are natively supported, such as encrypting. So certainly the benefits are huge, and certainly justify the change. So the reason it has not been more widely adopted yet is to find elsewhere (lack of easy GUI tools? Inertia?).

Comment: So I stand with @MarkAdler, this answer is based on incorrect premisses: tar does not allow partial file extraction, in fact it's the opposite, if you tar your files before feeding them to zip/Deflate, you lose the ability to partially extract files without uncompressing the archive, because tar can only make [solid archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression).

Answer (score 11):

File formats like .zip *require* the software to read the end of the file first, to read a catalog of filenames.  Conversely, tar stores that information in with the compressed stream.

The advantage of the tar way is that you can decompress data whilst reading it from a non-seekable pipe, like a network socket.

The advantage of the zip way is that, for a static file on disk, you can browse the contents and metadata without decompressing the whole archive first.

Both have their uses, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: No, you can both read and write zip files as a stream from and to a pipe.

Comment: That may be implementation-specific then, it certainly isn't supported by the original pkzip.

Comment: Yes, the software has to be written to support it.  The zip format supports it completely, with data descriptors that can follow the compressed data with the lengths and CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler, what software?  Infozip doesn't support unzipping from a pipe.

Comment: http://zlib.net/sunzip033.c.gz

Comment: Also Info-ZIP's zip supports compression to a stream.

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be some reluctance to answer all of your questions directly, with an apparent preference to use your question as a jumping off point for pontification.  So I'll give it a shot.

> Is there a performance penalty during the
>   aggregation/compression/decompression stages for using tar
>   encapsulated in gzip or bzip2, when compared to using a file format
>   that does aggregation and compression in the same data structure?
>   Assume the runtime of the compressor being compared is identical (e.g.
>   gzip and Deflate are similar).

No.  In fact since tar and gzip are usually two processes, you even get a smidge of multi-core speed benefit that an archiver like Info-ZIP's zip does not provide.  In terms of compression ratio, tar+gzip will usually do noticeably better than zip with deflate since the former can benefit from correlation between files, whereas the latter compresses files separately.  That compression benefit translates into a speed benefit when extracting, since a more-compressed archive decompresses in less time.

> Are there features of the tar file format that other file formats,
>   such as .7z and .zip do not have?

Yes, tar was designed for Unix, and has evolved over the years to be able to exactly record and restore every odd little nook and cranny of Unix file systems, even the nookier and crannier Mac OS X Unix file system.  zip is able to retain much of the metadata such as permissions, times, owners, groups, and symbolic links, but still not everything.  As an example, neither zip nor 7z can recognize or take advantage of sparse files, nor are they aware of or able to restore hard links.

> Since tar is such an old file format, and newer file formats exist
>   today, why is tar (whether encapsulated in gzip, bzip2 or even the new
>   xz) still so widely used today on GNU/Linux, Android, BSD, and other
>   such UNIX operating systems, for file transfers, program source and
>   binary downloads, and sometimes even as a package manager format?

Lots of other good answers here to that.  The best is that *it just works*, and you can keep updating it to better compression formats (e.g. xz) and still use the same tar format and even the same compiled tar utility.  If you just want to pack up a bunch of stuff, and then unpack it all on the other end, then there is little reason to use anything but one of the oldest, most complete, and most debugged pieces of software out there.

If you want random access, partial updates, or other things that need to deal with the contents piecemeal, or you want to be able to find out what's in it without reading the whole thing, then you would want to use a different format.

Comment: _CW_ stands for _Community Wiki_. See also [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/205162).

Comment: I guess it is CW because the question has more than 15 answers. When you posted this answer, because it is the 15th, the question and all of the answers were marked CW.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer says something that none of the other answers do, other than directly quoting the questions (which I wrote, BTW, because the original revision of the question was horrible enough to be closed as NARQ). Nice try though.

Comment: Um, ok.  Whatever you'd like to think is fine.  Your answer nor any other answer seems to address whether there is a performance penalty.  Your answer does not address the noticeable compression difference, though others do.  Since yours does not actually address performance (your performance section is actually about workflow, nothing about performance), no other answer answers everything in one place.  It is interesting that you wrote the performance penalty question, but you did not answer it!  Go figure.

Comment: By the way, your workflow discussion is about something no one ever does, which is to write a tar file to a disk and then compress it.  tar is always used either calling the compression program directly, or directly into a pipe to a compression program.

Answer (score 9):

Tar was created for doing backup full-fidelity backups of your filesystem, not just for transferring files around. As such, the tar utility is the most complete utility for creating an archive that preserves everything important about your filesystem structure.

This includes all these features that are missing in one or more competing tools:

- file ownership
- file permissions
- less-common file permissions (e.g. setuid, sticky bit)
- symbolic links
- hard links
- device entries (i.e. character and block devices)
- sparse files
- ACL entries (*not supported by all versions*)
- extended/user attributes (*not supported by all versions*)
- SElinux labels (*not supported by all versions*)

It also has the `--one-file-system` option which is extraordinarily useful when making backups.

Any time a new feature is added to filesystems, support gets added to `tar` first (or even exclusively). So it continues to be the most compatible way to save files.

Comment: This answer is the only one that makes sense. Thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 5):

We have lots of compressed files floating around today, MP3s, JPGs, Videos, tar.gz files, JAR packages, RPMs, DEBs and so on. If you need to bundle a bunch of these into a single file for transfer, then it is useful to have a 'tar' utility which only bundles the files without attempting to compress them.

Not only does it waste time and electricity to attempt to compress a compressed file, but it often results in a file which is bigger than the original.

Another use of it is to improve compression rates. For instance, if you 'tar' a bundle of log files and then gzip the result, you likely come up with a smaller file than if you compressed first, then bundled with 'tar'. And of course, using tar, you can choose any compression algorithm that you want, and specify options to optimize compression for your particular use case.

I find that tar' is very relevant today and I prefer it to use ZIP. In our office, everyone with Windows has 7-zip installed so, for us, tar files are fully cross-platform compatible.

Comment: You practically never see uncompressed `tar` files and there's a reason for that. `tar` uses very large chunks, meaning that you get a lot of padding at the end of files. To get rid of all these zeros, it almost always pays to just use `gzip` without giving it a second thought.

Comment: An amusing exception is that the gzip source code is available as a naked tar, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we should wonder why such "new" file formats performing both compression and aggregation (and I would add encryption) where not built on tar from the beginning instead of completely different tools.

As I understand it there are historical reasons (related to OS history, patents "protection", ability for software vendore to sell tools, etc.).

Now, as other response pointed it even now tar is not clearly inferior to other solutions and may be better on other aspects like ability to work on streams or Unix rights management.

If you read [the wikipedia article about tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) you can see another interesting fact. The article acknowledge [some shortcomings of tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Problems_and_limitations)... but does not suggest using zip instead (really zip format does not solve these shortcomings) but DAR.

I will end with a personal touch. Some times ago I had to create a file format for storing encrypted data. Using tar as a basis was handy (others made the same choice, for instance tar is the internal aggregation format for .deb packages). It was obvious to me that trying to compress data after encryption was totally useless, I had to perform compression as an independant step before encryption, and I was not either ready to use zip encryption (I wanted two key encryption with public and private keys). Using tar it worked as a breeze.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is "entrenchment in the culture". There are numerous people like me whose eyes glaze over if they are asked to process anything other than a compressed tar archive, or the occasional ZIP, if it came from the Windows world.

I don't want to hear about 7-Zip, RAR or anything else. If I have to install a program to uncompress your file, that is work. I will do it if it results in me being paid, or if the content is something I "must have" and isn't available in any other way.

One advantage of tar is that if you send someone a tarball, it is instantly recognized. The recipient can type the extraction commands using muscle memory.

The real question is: why are some people so obsessed with saving one more byte of space that they ask everyone else to waste time installing some exotic utility and learning how to use it? And then there are the stupid uses of exotic compression and archive formats. Does a [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) video with [AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) sound really need to be put into mult-part RAR?

The tar format may be old, but it stores everything that is relevant: file contents, paths, timestamps, permissions and ownerships. It stores not only symbolic links, but it can preserve hard link structure. It stores special files also, so a tape archive can be used for things like a minature `/dev` directory that is used during bootstrapping. You can put a Linux distribution together whose binary package format consists of nothing, but tarballs that are uncompressed relative to the filesystem root.

Comment: Re "So obsessed"... imagine you're stranded in warzone with a single hardened laptop, and the undersized 20G hard drive's nearly full, maybe a Gig left, and hearing the gunfire from far off, you'd really like to browse a 100MB .PDF manual that shows how to repair the jeep, but the file is in a 2 Gig .tgz file.  And the laptop runs a closed source strange proprietary OS, and you don't have root access to delete system files, not that it'd be obvious how to delete 4G+ without breaking the dearchiver or the PDF viewer.  If you could just extract that 100MB file...

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, but one of the reasons—not really an advantage, but a necessity—is for backwards compatibility.  There are plenty of systems running software for decades that might call `tar` for archiving.  It's not cost effective to hire someone to "fix" all the old systems.

Answer (score 3):

### tar is UNIX as UNIX is tar

In my opinion the reason of **still** using `tar` today is that it's one of the (probably rare) cases where the UNIX approach just made it perfectly right from the very beginning.

Taking a closer look at the stages involved in creating archives I hope you'll agree that the way the separation of different tasks takes place here is **UNIX philosophy** at its very best:

- one tool (`tar` to give it a name here) specialized in transforming **any** selection of files, directories and symbolic links including **all** relevant meta-data like timestamps, owners and permissions into one byte stream.
- and just another arbitrarily interchangeable tool (`gzip` `bz2` `xz` to name just a few options) that transforms **any** input stream of bytes into another (hopefully) smaller output stream.

Using such and approach delivers a whole couple of benefits to the user as well as to the developer:

- **extensibility**
  Allowing to couple `tar` with **any** compression algorithm already existing or **any** compression algorithm yet still to be developed **without** having to change anything on the inner workings of `tar` at all.

  As soon as the all brand new "hyper-zip-utra" or whater compression tool comes out you're already ready to use it embracing your new servant with the whole power of `tar`.
- **stability**
  `tar` has been in heavy use since the early 80es tested and been run on numberous operating systems and machines.

  Preventing the need to **reinvent** the wheel in implementing storing ownership, permissions, timestamps and the like **over and over again** for **every** new archiving tool not only saves a lot of (otherwise unnecessarily spent) time in development, but also guarantees the same **reliability** for every new application.
- **consistency** The user interface just stays the same all the time.

  There's no need to remember that to restore permissions using tool A you have to pass option `--i-hope-you-rember-this-one` and using tool B you have to use `--this-time-its-another-one`  while using tool C it's `--hope-you-didnt-try-with-tool-as-switch.

  Whereas in utilizing tool D you would have really messed up it if you didn't use `--if-you-had-used-tool-bs-switch-your-files-would-have-been-deleted-now`.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good answers, but they all neglect an important fact. Tar has a well-established ecosystem of users and developers in the Unix-like world. That keeps it going, just as ZIP is kept going by its DOS/Windows ecosystem. Having such an ecosystem is what sustains a technology, not its technical advantages.

Comment: Really good comment, I hadn't even thought of that, and that's a REALLY good point to make.

Answer (score 2):

Directly answering the specific questions you posed:

> Is there a performance penalty during the
>   aggregation/compression/decompression stages for using tar
>   encapsulated in gzip or bzip2, when compared to using a file format
>   that does aggregation and compression in the same data structure?
>   Assume the runtime of the compressor being compared is identical (e.g.
>   gzip and Deflate are similar).

There is a specific performance improvement, in general cases, using `tar` especially with the compression library built in (the `tar xvzf` or `tar xvjf` style command lines, where a compression library is used rather than a second process). This comes from two main causes:

- when processing a large number of relatively small files, especially those commonly used in distributing software, there is high redundancy. Compressing over many files results in higher overall compression than compressing individual files. And the "dictionary" is computed once for every chunk of input, not for each file.
- `tar` understands file systems. It is designed to save and restore a working/workable operating system. It deeply grasps exactly what is important on a UNIX file system, and faithfully captures and restores that. Other tools... not always, especially the zip family, which is better designed for sharing files amongst a family of OSs, where the document is the important thing, not a faithful OS sensitive copy.

> Are there features of the tar file format that other file formats,
>   such as .7z and .zip do not have?

Sparse file handling. Some of the direct database libs rely on sparse files - files where the data is nominally GB, but the actual data written and stored is much, much less, and only a few blocks of disk are actually used. If you use an unaware tool, then on decompressing, you end up with massive disk block consumption, all containing zeroes. Turning that back into a sparse file is... painful. If you even have the room to do it. You need a tool that grasps what a sparse file is, and respects that.

Metadata. Unix has evolved some strange things over the years. 14 character file names, long file names, links sym links, sticky bits, superuser bits, inherited group access permissions, etc. Tar understands and reproduces these. File sharing tools... not so much. A lot of people don't use links the way they could... If you've ever worked with software that does use links, and then used a non-aware tool to back up and restore, you now have a lot of independent files, instead of a single file with many names. Pain. Your software fails and you have disk bloat.

> Since tar is such an old file format, and newer file formats exist
>   today, why is tar (whether encapsulated in gzip, bzip2 or even the new
>   xz) still so widely used today on GNU/Linux, Android, BSD, and other
>   such UNIX operating systems, for file transfers, program source and
>   binary downloads, and sometimes even as a package manager format?

`tar` works. It does the job it is designed for, well. There have been other touted replacements (`cpio`, `pax`, etc, etc). But tar is installed on pretty much everything, and the compression libs it uses are also very common for other reasons. Nothing else has come along that substantially beats what tar does. With no clear advantages, and a lot of embedded use and knowledge in the community, there will be no replacement. Tar has had a lot of use over the years. If we get major changes in the way that we think of file systems, or non-text files somehow become the way to transfer code (can't currently imagine how, but ignore that...) then you could find another tool. But then that wouldn't be the type of OS that we now use. It'd be a different thing, organised differently and it would need its' own tools.

The most important question, I think, that you didn't ask, is what jobs 'tar' is ill-suited to.

`tar` with compression is fragile. You need the entire archive, bit for bit. In my experience, it is not resilient. I've had single bit errors result in multi-part archives becoming unusable. It does not introduce redundancy to protect against errors (which would defeat one of the questions you asked, about data compression). If there is a possibility of data corruption, then you want error checking with redundancy so you can reconstruct the data. That means, by definition, that you are not maximally compressed. You can't both have every bit of data of being required and carrying its maximum value of meaning (maximum compression) and have every bit of data being capable of loss and recovery (redundancy and error correction). So... what's the purpose of your archive? `tar` is great in high reliability environments and when the archive can be reproduced from source again. IME, it's actually worse at the original thing its' names suggests - tape archiving. Single bit errors on a tape (or worse, single bit errors in a tape head, where you lose one bit in every byte a whole tape or archive) result in the data becoming unusable. With sufficient redundancy and error detection and correction, you can survive either of those problems.

So... how much noise and corruption is there in the environment you're looking at, and can the source be used to regenerate a failed archive? The answer, from the clues that you've provided, is that the system is not noisy, and that source is capable of regenerating an archive. In which case, `tar` is adequate.

`tar` with compression also doesn't play well with pre-compressed files. If you're sending around already compressed data... just use tar, and don't bother with the compression stage - it just adds CPU cycles to do not much. That means that you do need to know what you're sending around and why. If you care. If you don't care about those special cases, then tar will faithfully copy the data around, and compress will faithfully *fail* to do much useful to make it smaller. No big problem, other than some CPU cycles.

Answer (score -3):

TAR is Tape Archive. It's been around for decades and it's widely used and supported. It is a mature product and takes care of the current needs as well as legacy ones.